# Nextjs build: Property does not exist on type 'PrismaClient

Tags: typescript, next.js, netlify, prisma

I'm running a NextJS app (TypeScript) with Prisma on Netlify. I recently added a new model called Trade. Here's the Prisma schema file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Contract {
  id              Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  contractAddress String  @unique
  baseUri         String
  tokenName       String  @default("")
  verified        Boolean @default(false)
}

model Trade {
  id      Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  tradeId Int @unique
  status  Int
}
```

I generated the migration file and ran the migrations in both local and production and verified the new table is present in both databases.

Everything runs fine locally but when I try to deploy to Netlify, I get this error in Netlify's build log:

```
Type error: Property 'trade' does not exist on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.
12:37:51 PM:   10 |     return res.status(400).send({ message: "No trade ID provided" })
12:37:51 PM:   11 |   try {
12:37:51 PM: > 12 |     const tradeInDatabase = await prisma.trade.findFirst({
```

The prisma plugin is added to the site and everything was working with other models until I added this new model. Trying to figure out why the Prisma client isn't aware of the new model in production.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve this by updating the build script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

This runs the prisma generate command in production environment and generates a new prisma client.